# SQL syntax error using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Invalid SQL statement.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nmc_cd.CDTitle LIMIT 0 , 30' at line 5

```
'$sql = "SELECT nmc_cd.CDTitle, nmc_cd.CDYear, nmc_cd.CDPrice, nmc_category.catDesc, nmc_publisher.pubName
FROM nmc_cd
NATURAL JOIN nmc_category
NATURAL JOIN nmc_publisher
ORDERBY nmc_cd.CDTitle
LIMIT 0 , 30";'
```

Comment: i m surprised, this question is up-voted.

Comment: @@tricor do some research before posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error because of `ORDERBY`:

```
...
NATURAL JOIN nmc_publisher 
ORDERBY nmc_cd.CDTitle LIMIT 0 , 30"
  /\
  Here
```

It is `ORDER BY` not `ORDERBY`, try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  nmc_cd.CDTitle, 
  nmc_cd.CDYear, 
  nmc_cd.CDPrice, 
  nmc_category.catDesc, 
  nmc_publisher.pubName 
FROM nmc_cd 
NATURAL JOIN nmc_category 
NATURAL JOIN nmc_publisher 
ORDER BY nmc_cd.CDTitle LIMIT 0 , 30"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nmc_cd.CDTitle, nmc_cd.CDYear, nmc_cd.CDPrice, nmc_category.catDesc, nmc_publisher.pubName FROM nmc_cd NATURAL JOIN nmc_category NATURAL JOIN nmc_publisher
ORDER BY nmc_cd.CDTitle LIMIT 0 , 30
```

use `ORDER BY` instead `ORDERBY`